# When are geodesic triangles well-defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, triangles, geodesic

Recall that a *Cartan–Hadamard manifold* is a complete, simply-connected Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ which has non-positive sectional curvature everywhere. One property of a Cartan–Hadamard manifold is that, given any two points $p,q \in M$, (up to reparameterisation) there is a unique geodesic segment which connects $p$ and $q$. This allows us to define a *geodesic triangle:* given $p,q,r \in M$ which are not colinear (i.e. not contained in the image of a single geodesic), we define the *geodesic triangle* $\Delta pqr$ to be the union of the images of the unique geodesic segments connecting the three points.

I am interested in geodesic triangles in complete Riemanian manifolds. However, this definition of a geodesic triangle isn't well-defined for a general complete Riemannian manifold, because there may be distinct distance-minimising geodesics connecting two points. For example, on $\mathbb S^2$, there are infinitely many distinct distance-minimising geodesics connecting antipodal points.

This motivates my question:

**Question.** *Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, and let $p \in M$. Does there exist $R > 0$ such that for any two points in the geodesic ball $B_R(p)$, there is a unique geodesic segment connecting the two points, whose image is contained in $B_R(p)$?*

I suspect that this is true: if we consider a geodesic ball of radius $R \leq \pi/2$ on $\mathbb S^2$, then any two points in the geodesic ball are connected by a unique distance-minimising geodesic segment (whose image is contained in the ball). However, I don't know where to start with the general case.

Comment: Yes, geodesics are locally length minimizing. Just choose [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) (in a small enough ball) and your geodesics will just because straight, radial lines from the center. If you want arbitrarily large triangles determined by three points, you will likely want a [uniquely geodesic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#U).

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen In normal coordinates at $p$, geodesics going through $p$ are radial lines. However, a geodesic that doesn't pass through $p$ does not in general have a nice formula. How do we pick $R> 0$?

Comment: You are right to call me out on that Joseph, since what you really want is a [geodesically convex neighborhood](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Geodesically_Convex_Neighborhood), and not just a geodesic ball. However, it turns out every small enough geodesic ball is geodesically convex, so we can just choose a small enough one to make this work. This is Theorem 6.17 in my copy of Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*, and a proof discussion can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4291768/269764) (which I see I was beaten to the punch to by 12 seconds)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you for your reply. I think what I am looking for is a geodesically-convex, uniformly-normal neighbourhood.